# Criar um site responsivo, e encapsular dentro de uma webview para internet lenta

Tags: html, material-design

Preciso criar um layout para um cliente mobile leve, devido ele morar no interior que só funciona internet com 384 kbps de velocidade por residencia.

minha pergunta e a seguinte para eu criar um layout preciso de usar um layout leve achei o material designer sera que fica bom e leve para usuários que vão acessar o aplicativo dele ?

logico considerando que vou tratar todas as image para o aplicativo que vai ser mudado a cada semana.

Caso alguém saiba de algo mais leve preciso de uma dica ai de vcs ok obrigado !